# Dynamically chose type depending on JSON content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, dynamic, deserialization

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 application I get a JSON response from an external server that contains an array of "fields". Each field is of an individual type and contains an array of values of that type.

I'd like to deserialize that JSON either into a DynamicObject so that I can access the indivudual value propreties or I need some kind of a child class chooser which decides which class, derived from a "ValueBase" class, is needed to access the different properties of the individual value object.

I hope you know what I mean... it's a little bit complicating.

I've already tried to deserialize it into a DynamicObject (a class that derives from DynamicObject that is). But I get error messages when accessing that object's dynamic properties in the View that the properties I'd like to display don't exist.

So how does a class that derives from DynamicObject have to look like to accept and grant access to the individual differen "value"-properties provided by the JSON code?

And if that wasn't possible or the wrong way to go, how would I have to implement a suitable type chooser class?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this is an ASP.Net-specific problem, it might benefit from being tagged as such, to get more attention from the ASP.Net people.

Comment: You're right. I knew I've forgotten something... okay, it's tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kinda solved it myself.

Instead of directly converting the returned JSON object (a JSON array to be more precise) into a specific class I fetch it as a *dynamic* and give it into the constructor of a class that contains a collection of instances of another class the object actually ought to be of (I get a JSON array returned from the webservice anyway). In the constructor of the collection class I decide depending on a value of the JSON object of which inherited class the new object is gonna be and put that into the collection. Yeah, I walked that way afoot somehow but it works.

Looks like this:

```
public CollectionClass(dynamic dyn)
{
  foreach(var item in dyn.items) {
    switch((string)item.external_id) { // might have used a Dictionary instead but...
      case "member":
        this._collection.Add(new Member(item));
        break;
      case "date":
        this._collection.Add(new Date(item));
        break;
      default: break;
    }
  }
}
```

The Member-class itself contains a similar constructor which also requires a *dynamic* parameter. And it also "builds itself up" depending on values inside the *item*.

If there's any easier way or a "royal road" of achieving this I'd be grateful for any further advice.